# django-wysiwyg: Use YUI SimpleEditor instead of the default Editor

Tags: django, django-wysiwyg

I'm using django-wysiwyg in my django app, and by default it makes use of YUI's Editor. I'd rather it to use the SimpleEditor, because it's, well, simpler.

Is there an easy way of doing this that doesn't require forking the project? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a `django_wysiwyg` directory under my templates directory, and under it placed:

```
- simple_yui
    - includes.html
    - editor_instance.html
```

Where `editor_instance.html` simply extends the default one and `includes.html` is a copy of the default one with `SimpleEditor` instead of `Editor`. Then I just had to add to my settings:

```
DJANGO_WYSIWYG_FLAVOR = 'simple_yui'
```

And that what that. Not very clean, but did the trick

Answer (score 0):

You could always just define a `Media` class in the appropriate class on your `admin.py` file which includes Javascript to support the WYSIWYG editor.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import MyModel

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
         js = [
              '/path/to/static/js/that/includes/wysiwyg.js',
              '/path/to/static/js/that/replaces/textarea/with/wysiwyg.js',
         ]

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```